# Seeking 19th century marriage record for Wolf and Amélie Thalmann whose descendants settled in Mannheim?

Tags: germany, marriage-records, baden-wuerttemberg

Richard (1861-1938, died in Paris, France) from the Thalmann family of Mannheim (in south-west Germany) had about four siblings:

- Ernst (founder of Ladenburg-Thalmann Bank in NYC in 1875),
- Flora (later Rosen), and
- two(?) others.

The parents were, according to Richard's marriage records (Paris, c. 1894) named Wolf and Amélie, although this may be a francophonisation.

How could I find a marriage record for Wolf and Amélie?

Comment: This is another question that is far to general to be answered and needs its focus sharpening.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl, I'll talk with my grandmother. I don't know how much she wants to let out on the internet. I'll edit in dates where I have them.

Comment: @NoahfromFrankfurt It will still be a very broad question that can’t be answered.

Comment: Try to shift the focus of your question away from your specific people to what *information* you would like to find.  A good question which is focused on a time and place can get you answers that will help you find your family *and* everyone else whose family came from the same place.  It isn't necessary to post specific names to write a good question.